# ccpd starting problem in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: printing, canon

How can add the following command to start up ?
Now I manually enter this command in each time the computer start up for using Canon LBP 2900 printer

sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start

Answer (score 0):

Hare's a complete guide to get Canon's official CAPT drivers installed and automatically starting.

[CanonCaptDrv190](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190)